# Inserting an Array from a Jade Form

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I'm a complete novice when it comes to node.js and jade and I'm getting myself confused!! 
I have a schema for Clients which holds next of Kin

```
nextOfKin: [{name:String,contact:Number}]
```

I have a from to create Clients and I have two input fields for Next of Kin Name and Contact info

```
label(for="nextOfKin") Next of Kin <br />
input#nextOfKin(name="nextOfKin")

label(for="contact") Next of Kin Contact <br />
input#contact(name="contact")
```

I can't figure out how to pass these as an object into the database eg ("John Doe",123456)

Answer (score 0):

Nest your input elements within a form, and they will then be available in the request body. In your jade template:

```
form(name="search", action="/NextOfKin", method="post")
  label(for="nextOfKin") Next of Kin <br />
  input#nextOfKin(name="nextOfKin")

  label(for="contact") Next of Kin Contact <br />
  input#contact(name="contact")

  input(type='submit', value='Update')
```

The values of the input fields for the form will then be available in the callback of your route definition. For example, if you are using express and the user selected 'foo' for nextOfKin and 'bar' for contact:

```
app.post('/NextOfKin', function(res, req){
    console.log("req.body", req.body); // req.body { nextOfKin: 'foo', contact: 'bar' }
    // call your logic to create a client, which should have a callback passed in to render the result of the update (success or error etc)
});
```